# Swift Protocols: Difference between { get } and { get set } with concrete examples?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm pretty new to Swift, and although I've read Apple's documentation and many topics and threads about this, I still can't understand what's the difference between `{ get }` and `{ get set }`. I mean, I'm looking for an explanation with a concrete example.

Like, for example:

```
protocol PersonProtocol {
    var firstName: String { get }
    var lastName: String { get set }
}
```

What would be the actual difference between these two properties? I tried to play with these properties in a playground:

```
struct Person: PersonProtocol {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

var p = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Lennon")
print(p.firstName) // John
print(p.lastName) // Lennon
p.firstName = "Paul"
p.lastName = "McCartney"
print(p.firstName) // Paul
print(p.lastName) // McCartney
```

Did not help... Thanks for your help.

Comment: See: https://medium.com/@chetan15aga/swift-protocols-properties-distinction-get-get-set-32a34a7f16e9

Comment: `var` store property has both setter and getter

Comment: For `firstName` you can only get it meaning you can only call it and you can set it. with `lastName`, you can both get and set it, you can also change it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`protocol` — is a *requirement* of some *minimal* interface of the type implementing it.

- `var name: Type { get }` requires type to have *property* with at least a `getter` (accessible from outside of the type, not `private`), i.e. outside code should be able to **read** value of the property. In the implementing type it could be `let name: Type`, `var name: Type`, `private(set) var name: Type`, `fileprivate(set) var name: Type`, etc.
- `var name: Type { get set }` requires type to have *property* with both accessible `getter` and `setter`, i.e. outside code should be able to **read** and **write** to the property. Here only `var name: Type` would be allowed.

If `protocol` requires for `getter` but you also provide a `setter` — it's not against `protocol` requirements.
But if `protocol` requires for both `getter` and `setter` — you must provide both, and not having any of them won't be valid implementation.

---

Your `Person` class defined *both* properties as `var`(with accessible `getter` and `setter`) therefore you can change them both. But `PersonProtocol` haven't required ability to set `firstName`.

And as @JoakimDanielson shows, if you will use just interface required by `protocol` you won't be to change the `firstName` value.

Comment: Best explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

You are creating a variable of type `Person` and there are no restrictions on that struct. If you instead create a variable of type `PersonProtocol` then `firstName` will be read only

```
var p1: PersonProtocol = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Lennon")
print(p1.firstName) // John
print(p1.lastName) // Lennon
p1.firstName = "Paul" <== error: cannot assign to property: 'firstName' is a get-only property
```